# Scale issues - Some windows are too big after setting scaling back

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

So I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop which as a high resolution display which worked well with scale factor 2.

Now I have connected an external monitor which requires a scale factor 1. I update this in System Settings, and some of the windows are scaled correctly (example: HexChat, Chrome, Launcher) but others are too big (Terminal, File Browser):

[image]

How can I scale down all windows?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For others with the same issue, if you want to change the scale mode on Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), there are three places to change:

System Preferences > Screen Display > Scale for menu and title bars:

[image]

Tweak Tool > Fonts > Scaling Factor:

[image]

Tweak Tool > Window > Window Scaling:

[image]

Comment: I can open these Windows, but my UI is so big I can't even reach these options - they're all off the screen.